# How to reduce Windows shutdown time?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, troubleshooting, shutdown, malware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does it sometimes take a long time for windows to shutdown?](https://superuser.com/questions/23882/why-does-it-sometimes-take-a-long-time-for-windows-to-shutdown)

A windows XP SP3 boots fast but take quite a time to shudown

How to reduce it, I wonder?

PS
Recently I removed a virus from machine

Comment: Why does it matter? Just walk away...

Comment: It could be a problem if it made restarting the computer too slow.

Comment: I can shut down any PC in 5 seconds or less... Gracefully or not, is a different story  :-P